# Matching a Table and a List and building a new Table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a Table which includes {Numbers, Probabilities}.
For example A= {{1,0.5},{2,0.25}, {3,0.1},{4,0.9}……{100,0.1}}. Put attention that the numbers are 1,2….100 in order.
I have a List of random numbers (same length like the Table and can include duplicates).
For example B={2,5,100,500, 61,250,8……19}.
I would like to build an short algorithm that will :
 (1) Choose each number in List B and check if its appear in Table A, 
(2) If it's there, for example "2" it will be a term in a new Table C which includes again {Number, Probability from Table A) = {2,0.25} . Here we build a new Table C.
(3) If the number in List B does not appears in A than Null (nothing).
I will be thankful to get a solution.

Comment: So lists `A` and `B` have 100 elements, but list `C` will have a length some number less than 100?

Comment: Yes, That's the idea.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by `Null` - do you mean nothing, no element there, in which list `C` will be smaller than lists `A` and lists `B`, or do you specifically want to have the word `Null` in those positions?  From your answer above I assume you want the first, but others have interpreted your question as it was written

Answer (score 2):

For a shorter example, lets take `A` and `B` to have 20 elements instead of 100, and have the integers in `B` run from 0 to 40,

```
nElements = 20;
maxB = 40;
listA = Table[{n, RandomReal[]}, {n, nElements}]
listB = RandomInteger[maxB, nElements]
(* {{1, 0.350025}, {2, 0.651077}, {3, 0.444575}, {4, 
  0.261574}, {5, 0.40258}, {6, 0.670888}, {7, 0.388662}, {8, 
  0.675527}, {9, 0.496563}, {10, 0.356305}, {11, 0.58421}, {12, 
  0.93864}, {13, 0.984511}, {14, 0.871462}, {15, 0.581234}, {16, 
  0.643948}, {17, 0.373181}, {18, 0.821704}, {19, 0.950593}, {20, 
  0.921725}} *)
(* {11, 24, 28, 35, 6, 28, 39, 23, 33, 8, 3, 27, 33, 18, 18, 
24, 16, 19, 5, 19} *)
```

This will give you the list you are after:

```
listA[[Pick[listB, 1 <= # <= nElements & /@ listB]]]
(* {{3, 0.0380246}, {11, 0.311671}, {14, 0.842235}, {8, 
  0.381485}, {6, 0.43467}, {14, 0.842235}, {16, 0.560073}, {11, 
  0.311671}, {8, 0.381485}, {3, 0.0380246}} *)
```

Comment: Thx a lot JasonB.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that follows your algorithm to the letter, you would need something like this:

```
Map[ If[ MemberQ[ A[[;; , 1]] , #],  AppendTo[c, A[[#]]]] &, B]
```

I used c instead of C because C is a protected symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = With[{l1 = #, l2 = #2}, If[MemberQ[l1[[All, 1]], #], l1[[#]]] & /@ l2] &;

SeedRandom[3]
n = 10;
probs = Differences@Join[{0}, Sort@RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], n - 1], {1}];
listA = Transpose[{Range[n], probs}]
```

> {{1, 0.00869692}, {2, 0.130583}, {3, 0.0413228}, {4, 0.166427}, {5, 
>         0.0572686}, {6, 0.074256}, {7, 0.0501474}, {8, 0.0498856}, {9, 
>         0.181763}, {10, 0.239651}}

```
listB = RandomInteger[{1, 2 n}, 10]
```

> {14, 10, 1, 9, 9, 20, 15, 6, 3, 12}

```
listC = f[listA, listB];
listC
```

> {Null, {10, 0.239651}, {1, 0.00869692}, {9, 0.181763}, {9, 
>         0.181763}, Null, Null, {6, 0.074256}, {3, 0.0413228}, Null}

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting the question as [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) has [done](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113929/106), and using listA and listB as given in [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113929/106):

```
Cases[listA, {#, x_} :> Sequence[#, x]] & /@ listB /. {} -> Null
```

> {Null, {10, 0.239651}, {1, 0.00869692}, {9, 0.181763},
>
> {9, 0.181763}, Null, Null, {6, 0.074256}, {3, 0.0413228}, Null}

Or

```
Cases[listA, {#, x_} :> Sequence[#, x]] & /@ listB /. {} -> Nothing
```

> {{10, 0.239651}, {1, 0.00869692}, {9, 0.181763}, {9, 0.181763},
>
> {6, 0.074256}, {3, 0.0413228}}